# Gröbner basis of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, gcd-and-lcm, groebner-basis, monomial-order

I have the following problem:

*Let $I, J ⊂ S $ be ideals and $<$ a monomial order on $S$. Let
$G, G'$ be Gröbner bases of $I$, respectively $J$, with respect to $<$ . Prove that if
$\,\operatorname{in}_<(g)$ and $\,\operatorname{in}_<(g')$ are relatively prime for any $g ∈ G$, $g' ∈ G'$, then $G ∪ G'$
is a Gröbner basis of $I + J$.*

I would be grateful if someone would help me with some advice.

Comment: If you prove the relatively prime part then note the Chinese remainder theorem for rings

http://www.math.clemson.edu/~macaule/classes/m20_math4120/slides/math4120_lecture-7-07_h.pdf

Two ideal $I$ and $J$ are coprime  (relatively prime) if $I+J =R$ (the ring)

Answer (score 0):

The argument presented here is taken from the book *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* by Cox, Little and O'Shea. As is often the case with this kind of problem, we will apply Buchberger's criterion:

> **Theorem (Buchberger's criterion).**
> Let $I$ be an ideal of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Then a basis $G = \{g_1,\dots,g_s\}$ of $I$ is a Gröbner basis if and only if $S(g_i,g_j) \rightarrow_G 0$ for all $i \neq j$.

Here, the notation $f \rightarrow_G 0$ means that $f$ has a standard representation with respect to $G$, i.e. we can write
\begin{equation*}
f = h_1g_1 + \dots + h_sg_s,
\end{equation*}
where $\deg(f) \geq \deg(h_ig_i)$ whenever $h_ig_i \neq 0$. Notice that if $G \subseteq H$, then $f \rightarrow_G 0$ implies that $f \rightarrow_H 0$.

Write $G = \{g_1,\dots,g_s\}$ and $G'= \{g_1',\dots,g_t'\}$. Without loss of generality, suppose that all the elements of $G \cup G'$ have leading coefficient $1$. Since $G$ is a Gröbner basis of $I$, we know that $S(g_i,g_j) \rightarrow_{G \cup G'} 0$ for all $1 \leq i,j \leq s$, and similarly for $S(g_i',g_j')$. It remains to consider $S(g_i,g_j')$. Writing $g_i = x^\alpha+p$ and $g_j' = x^\beta+q$, where $\text{in}_<(g_i) = x^\alpha$ and $\text{in}_<(g_j') = x^\beta$, we compute
\begin{equation*}
S(g_i,g_j') = x^\beta\cdot g_i-x^\alpha\cdot g_j' = (g_j'-q)g_i-(g_i-p)g_j' = p\cdot g_j'-q\cdot g_i.
\end{equation*}
We claim that $S(g_i,g_j') = p\cdot g_j'-q\cdot g_i$ is a standard representation. Indeed, the leading terms $\text{in}_<(p\cdot g_j') = \text{in}_<(p)\cdot x^\beta$ and $\text{in}_<(q\cdot g_i) = \text{in}_<(q)\cdot x^\alpha$ have different degrees (otherwise $x^\alpha$ and $x^\beta$ wouldn't be relatively prime), hence
\begin{equation*}
\deg(S(g_i,g_j')) = \max\{\deg(p\cdot g_j'),\deg(q\cdot g_i)\}.
\end{equation*}